# Container format supported by Directshow

Tags: windows, video, directshow

I'm trying to encode video files in windows using DirectShow filter graph. My source is a Push source filter injecting raw images to filter graph. I want to support most of the codec and most of the container format :).

However I've just found support of .avi, .asf and .wmv container formats.

I would like to know if DirectShow also support .mp4, .flv, .mov and .3gp formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DirectShow is format-agnostic. All mentioned container formats are supported in DirectShow through respective filters. Standard filters cover some formats, and for other one would need third party filters, a notable example of such are [GDCL MPEG-4 Filters](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4/).